# add custom value to cart from a form, prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm creating a simple Prestashop module that places a form in CMS pages. That form will return a custom value (and a new product) that I need to be redirected to the cart after clicking a "submit" button.

How can I send the data to the cart?

Thank you!

Rui

Answer (score 0):

Every customer has a unique cart ID.
1 ) After submit put information to mysql table
2 ) hook module to cart step
3 ) Check if this customer and cart id equal and do what you need to do.

I think its easiest and simplest way to do it. Rather than override system files. Even more you talking about module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript class in prestashop to control the cart. 
Simply call ajaxCart.add(params)

This function will add the product to the cart  with ajax.